# How to solve this fractional PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$F_x = F*F_y = F^2*Fz$,

where $F = F(x,y,z)$.

*So far I could solve the reduced problem considering either of the equalities:*

$F_x = F*F_y$

*Which yields me:*

$F(x,y) = \frac{-y}{x+c}$

Comment: try separation of variables - write $f(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$

Comment: This is not, strictly speaking, a "fractional PDE," unless your differential operators have some unstated fractional order.

Comment: @WW1 I couldn't find a solution of that form

Comment: @MichaelLee my bad, I didn't know how to classify this PDE so I thought fracional would be intuitive since the function itself equals the fraction of its partial derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F_x = F*F_y = F^2*Fz$$

If I well understand, you have two dependent PDEs.

FIRST PDE :$\quad F_x - F*F_y=0$

With the method of characteristics, the system of characteristic equations is :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-F}=\frac{dF}{0}$$
A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad dF=0 \quad\to\quad F=c_1$

A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad \frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-c_1} \quad\to\quad y+c_1x=c_2\quad\text{or}\quad y+xF=c_2$

The general solution of the PDE is expressed on the form of the implicit equation :
$$F=\Phi(y+xF)$$
where $\Phi(X)$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

The particular solution that you found $\quad F=\frac{-y}{x+c}\quad$ corresponds to the case of the particular function $\quad \Phi(X)=-X/c$ .

Since $F$ includes an independent variable $z$, the correct writing is :
$$F(x,y,z)=\Phi\big(z\:,\:y+xF(x,y,z)\big)$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary differentiable function of two variables.

SECOND PDE :$\quad F_y - F*F_z=0$

The same method leads to the general solution on implicit form :
$$F(x,y,z)=\Psi\big(x\:,\:z+yF(x,y,z)\big)$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary differentiable function of two variables.

NOTE :

Alternatively we could solve the PDE : $\quad F_x = F^2*Fz\quad$ which leads to
$$F(x,y,z)=\Theta\big(y\:,\:z+xF^2(x,y,z)\big)$$
where $\Theta$ is an arbitrary differentiable function of two variables.

But the functions $\Phi$ , $\Psi$ and $\Theta$ are not independent. So only two of them are sufficient to solve the problem.

RESULT :

The general solution of the associated PDEs $\quad F_x = F*F_y = F^2*Fz \quad$ is :
$$F(x,y,z)=\Phi\big(z\:,\:y+xF(x,y,z)\big)=\Psi\big(x\:,\:z+yF(x,y,z)\big)$$
where $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are two independent arbitrary differentiable functions, each one of two variables.

Usually the arbitrary functions are determined according to some boundary conditions. Since there is no boundary condition specified in the wording of the question, one cannot go further.

Comment: Could the boundary condition F(0,y,z) = -z/y determine the arbitrary functions?

Comment: Yes, with the condition $\quad F(0,y,z)=-z/y\quad$ the solution is : $$x\left(F(x,y,z)\right)^2+yF(x,y,z)+z=0$$which means:$$F(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}-\frac{z}{y}\quad\text{if}\quad x=0\\ \frac{-y+\sqrt{y^2-4xz}}{2x}\quad\text{if}\quad x\neq 0\quad\text{and}\quad y>0\\ \frac{-y-\sqrt{y^2-4xz}}{2x}\quad\text{if}\quad x\neq 0\quad\text{and}\quad y<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: great! Thanks :)